# Alternative to Screenium for Linux and splitting extracting audio from video

Tags: linux, extract, screen-capture

On my Mac I use Screenium to record screencast or streaming video.  I can then take that and extract the audio from the file if I like.  I'm looking for a way to do this on Linux.

I've heard of [Screenr](http://screenr.com/), [Wink](http://www.debugmode.com/wink/), and [gtk- recordmydesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php).

What is the best way to record screencasts and streaming video, and what is the best way to split audio from the file aftwerwards in Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the best way to record screencasts and streaming video,

[RecordMyDesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php) / [Instanbul](http://live.gnome.org/Istanbul)

> what is the best way to split audio
>   from the file aftwerwards in Linux?

[WinFF](http://winff.org/html_new/), is the GUI frontend to ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

For capture [Xvidcap](http://xvidcap.sourceforge.net/) works well. To pull audio out of that file you can use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/), like so:

```
ffmpeg -i capture_vid.mpg -ab 128 -ar 44100 extracted_audio.mp3
```

For GUI-based audio extraction, you can use [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) and the Convert/Stream feature

Comment: i'd prefer a GUI if there is one